# Базовый класс Фигура

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Базовый класс Фигура с полем «название фигуры» и методом «Печать названия». 
Производный класс Шар с полем Радиус. Переопределить для него функцию Печать так,чтобы она выводила данные о шаре на экран. Описать в классе дополнительную функцию Объем, вычисляющую объем фигуры и печатающую результат на 
экран.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Figura
{
protected:      
    string name;
public:
    Figura(string name){ this->name = name; }

    void show_name() { cout << name << endl; }
};
class Shar : public Figura {
    protected: 
        float radius;
    public:
        Shar(string name, float radius):Figura(name) {this->radius = radius; }

        void show_name() {cout <<"Фигура: " << name << endl; }

        void vRadius() {
            v = (4*M_PI*radius*radius*radius)/3;
            cout << "Объем шара: " <<v<<endl;
        }
    private:
        float v;

};

int main() {
    Figura f("Фигура");
    f.show_name();
    cout<<"----------------------------------"<<endl;
    Shar shar("Шар",7);
    shar.show_name();
    shar.vRadius();
}
```

Comment: Напишите в чём ваш вопрос, что не работает. У меня кстати пример не компилируются нужно перед инклюдом math.h написать строку `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` и будет компилироваться. У меня код успешно всё выводит, вроде правильный.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul, метка [tag:инспекция-кода] говорит о том, что всё работает.

Answer (score 2):

для инициализации вместо присваивания в теле конструктора

```
this->name = name;
```

лучше использовать более эффективную во всех отношениях инициализацию полей в списке инициализации конструктора

```
Figura(string name)
 : name(name){
}
```

тоже относится и к классу Shar, в котором вы, кстати, использовали этот способ, но не полностью

```
Shar(string name, float radius):Figura(name){
 this->radius = radius;
}
```

этот конструктор лучше записать так

```
Shar(string name, float radius)
 : Figura(name), radius(radius){
}
```

приватное поле **v** используется только как локальная переменная в методе **vRadius**, поэтому ее, стоило бы сделать локальной переменной в этом методе. Но, если вы планируете впоследствии использовать рассчитанное значение, то приватное поле для нее - это нормально. Но тошда стоит придерживаться принципа - **одна функция - одно действие(логическое)** Т.е. **vRadius** не должна вычислять значение объема и выводить его. Стоит разделить ее на две функции. Одну - для вычисления объема, вторую для отображения объема

```
void calcVolume() {
 v = (4*M_PI*radius*radius*radius)/3;
}

void show_volume() {
 cout << "Объем шара: " <<v<<endl;
}
```

ну, а так как объем шара однозначно зависит от радиуса, то можно перенести вычисление объема в конструктор и инициализировать его сразу при создании объекта

```
Shar(string name, float radius)
 : Figura(name), radius(radius), v(4*M_PI*radius*radius*radius/3){
}
```

В итоге получиться так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Figura{
protected:      
    string name;
public:
    Figura(string name)
    :   name(name){}

    void show_name() {
        cout << name << endl;
    }
};

class Shar : public Figura {
    protected: 
        float radius;
    public:
        Shar(string name, float radius)
            :   Figura(name), radius(radius), v(4*M_PI*radius*radius*radius/3){
        }

        void show_name(){
            cout <<"Фигура: " << name << endl;
        }

        void show_volume() {
            cout << "Объем шара: " <<v<<endl;
        }

    private:
        float v;

};

int main() {
    Figura f("Фигура");
    f.show_name();
    cout<<"----------------------------------"<<endl;
    Shar shar("Шар",7);
    shar.show_name();
    shar.show_volume();
}
```

Comment: `Figura(name), radius(radius), v(4*M_PI*radius*radius*radius/3)` - а это не раскладывание граблей на будущее? А со всем остальным согласен. Я бы ещё float заменил на double.

Comment: честно сказать, грабель не вижу. А вот виртуальный деструктор еще можно было бы добавить.

Comment: Да, наверное, грабель нет. Вообще грабли в порядке инициализации свойств, но тут вычисленные свойства нигде не используются, так что должно работать.